# Inserting rows of a table along with a separate value into another table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, insert

I have two tables - table1 and table2

table1 has `14 columns` and table2 has `15 columns`. The `first 14 columns` in both the tables are the same and in the same order. I want to copy certain rows of table1 into table2 and insert a timestamp into the 15th column. How to write the query for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO t2(c1,c2,c3)
SELECT c1,c2, NOW() FROM t1;
```

You could use an *, but that's a recipe for future problems: The query will fail when you change the column definitions in one of your tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into table2
select *, current_timestamp
from table1
where table1.some_column = 'whatever' -- etc
```

Although handy, this is brittle. It is cleaner and better to name all the columns:

```
insert into table2 (col1, col2, col3, ..., col15, col16)
select col1, col2, col3, ...,  col15, current_timestamp
from table1
where table1.coln = 'whatever' -- etc
```

Comment: How does the db know that "current_timestamp" is not a column of the "table1", since it is alos included int the select statement itself

Comment: @Ashwin `current_timestamp` is an in-built keyword in postgres - it's a reserved word. You *can* have a column name of this, but you must always quote it when using it, ie `select "current_timestamp" ...`. Using reserved words as column names should be vigorously avoided

Comment: okay..what if I want to insert somthing other than timestamp, say a string in the col16. Can a query be written for that.